# How I can see that vsftpd's users write as the password on my ubuntu?

Tags: ftp, log, vsftpd

I have ubuntu 20.04 and I give ftp access for 35 customers for uploading files for us. Everything was right but today one customer change his server and cannot connect. He wrote a wrong password. I see in vsftpd log his try and see that he wrote wrong password. It's look like:

```
Wed Dec 20 08:31:39 2023 [pid 30714] [customer12_ftp_user_name] FTP command: Client "102.77.241.172", "PASS <password>"
Wed Dec 20 08:31:41 2023 [pid 30713] [customer12_ftp_user_name] FAIL LOGIN: Client "102.77.241.172"
```

I need to see what is real password in first line in code block above.

My customer knows correct password. I know his correct password and can change it. But he ask me - look at your server and show me what I write incorrect in password! How can I set up my ubuntu or vsftpd for writing wrong password in log? I agree to write all my ftp users passwords in log for every connect for my server, as correct and as incorrect. For just I only want to see what this customer write in password field at now.

Thanks for any useful answers!

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* earlier this year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: I'm sorry, I look at now and my server actually use ubuntu 20.04. But it don't change vsftpd or something else in this case. Passwords for ftp users don't show in logs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem using:

```
sudo tcpdump port ftp -A
```